# How to get the background colour name of an excel cell(xlsx) using apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Requirement: I want to read an excel sheet and perform some action on the cells that are highlighted in the sheet i.e the cells which have their background colour as yellow.

I went through all the other similar posts but could not get the required information.

I tried using `getFillBackgroundColor()` which returns me value 64 each time for every colour. I tried using `getFillBackgroundColorColor()` which returns a colour object but I could not find a way to resolve it to the color name.

Please If anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the samples at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills, you might need to use `getFillForegroundColor()`

Answer (score 0):

Fills feel a bit unnatural to me, but it is just the nature of the beast. The fill itself is the cell background, but the fill itself has a foreground and background. So our typical two layer view of the world (foreground/background) doesn't work. In Excel we have three layers: Text color, Fill Foreground color, and Fill Background color. The Solid Fill happens to use the Fill Foreground color rather than the Fill Background color. Only two color fills have a Fill Background Color.

So if you have a solid "background", that means you have a solid fill which means you need to use `getFillForegroundColor()`.